# Can camel-jetty option 'chunked' be used in a <to> tag?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

Can we use the option 'chunked' provided by camel-jetty component in a <to> tag as shown below?

```
<route trace="true" id="SimpleProxy">
    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8299/test2?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:9001/rest?chunked=true"/>
</route>
```

Or it can only be used for a consumer endpoint in a <from> tag?

I already have a server listening on the uri specified in the <to> tag.

The documentation doesn't that chunked can only be used for a consumer endpoint .

Comment: did you try to add it in the to tag?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that and it doesn't work. I am thinking that it can be used only on a consumer endpoint as in case of a <from> tag , since the uri i specify in <to> is not a jetty managed endpoint like the one in <from> tag.

Comment: Use then the camel - http component.  It is used for producer endpoint.